# Scraping "href" using Chrome

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to scrape the href attribute from a website using Google Chrome.

This is the website: https://pool.pm/addr1qxlxmpqamdnzs9gpgvjnsxehu4pd95a9ddhhcuxadvzv69jjtu4lhppapqxxgtsxweackk6se5m3zp9qkadsu62de8uqrp3dk4/%409e9e948d

This is a snippet of HTML code that I am trying to retrieve.
[image]

I noticed that "topics" returns empty values. This makes the rest of my code irrelevant.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub openurl()

Dim myurl As String
Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim topics As Object
Dim titleElem As Object

myurl = "https://pool.pm/addr1qxlxmpqamdnzs9gpgvjnsxehu4pd95a9ddhhcuxadvzv69jjtu4lhppapqxxgtsxweackk6se5m3zp9qkadsu62de8uqrp3dk4/%409e9e948d"

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
request.Open "GET", myurl, False
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
request.send
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
html.body.innerHTML = response

Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("hc ah cx s e wc ccx ccy lnk")

Sheets("main").Range("A3").Value = topics.getElementsByTagName("a").href

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The site is not generating HTML without JavaScript, so you have the wrong URL.
This currently has nothing to do with `Chrome`. You're making a simple HTTP Request.

This is the async resource that has the item you want:

https://pool.pm/wallet/addr1qxlxmpqamdnzs9gpgvjnsxehu4pd95a9ddhhcuxadvzv69jjtu4lhppapqxxgtsxweackk6se5m3zp9qkadsu62de8uqrp3dk4

It returns a json Response, one of the fields in an array of `tokens`.

You have to parse the json Response with VBA.

Entry 207 has the item you want.
You could probably just loop the `tokens` and access `.name` and `.policy` to generate all the href links you want.

```
{
    ...
    tokens[207].policy = "9e9e948d01bc64e29c26fbf85922d8d80dbf987222ffb45a6fe9f480",
    tokens[207].name = "DungeonLootersClubWeapon0112"
}
```